# Dipoles lengths underwater vs on land

Tags: rf, wireless, radio, physics, dipole

A submarine (for example) uses a VLF communications system to remain in contact with its headquarters while submerged. The submarine drags a resonant dipole wire antenna behind it in the water. The Headquarters uses a resonant wire dipole antenna mounted on poles along the coast. The frequency is 20 kHz.

My first question is: How long (end-to-end) is the antenna at the headquarters?

and

If light propagates more slowly in water than in air, and if the speed of light in water is only ¾ as fast as in air, how long (end-to-end) is the antenna being dragged behind the submarine?

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: If my calculations are correct than, the wavelength of the carrier propagating in air is 15km, therefore, the length (end-to-end) of the dipole at the headquarters would be 7.5km.  But I have know about the length of the dipole underwater.

Comment: Consider that a shorter dipole can be made resonant by using a [loading coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Loading_coil).

Answer (score 1):

The velocity of electromagnetic propagation in any given medium is given by V = c/(sqr[ErMr]) where Er is the relative permittivity of the material and Mr is the relative permeability of the material. In free space, these relative values are 1.

What you therefore need to know are these values (I have not looked around but I am sure they  may be found). It is quite likely that ocean salinity will have a bearing on these, and salinity of the oceans varies quite dramatically.

From that, Lamba' = V/f where Lambda' is the effective wavelength of the signal in your new medium.

This is an effective length, but the actual antenna can be much smaller by using techniques such as base loading where a large coil is used at the base of the antenna (hence the name).

PJS

Answer (score 0):

The equation you need to use is: c = lambda*f, where c is the speed of light, lambda is the wavelength and f is the frequency. 
When going from one medium to another, f always stays constant. 
Also, a resonant dipole is 1/2 of the wavelength. 
So, to solve your problem you need to compute the wavelength in each medium and then divide the number by 2.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to see a good answer so I will say what I would do if I had to do the job Firstly I would multiply the length by the reciprocal of the square root of 80  By length I mean the length on land so the dipole is much shorter than its land lubbing cousin BUT with practical numbers you will still be running a loading coil so accuracy isn't super important as it only slightly changes the required loading inductance The number 80 comes from the approx. dielectric const of water which will vary and I have assumed that the relative peamability is unity